# What does a GraphQL resolver return for an object with a relation?

Tags: graphql, resolver

If I have

```
type Post {
  title: String!
  body: String!
  author: User!
}
type User {
  name: String
  posts: [Post!]!
}
type Query {
  users: [User!]!
}
```

What does the resolver `users` return? I understand it can return an empty list, but when it returns a populated list I'm not sure how to handle that. Intuitively, it seems to me like it should be infinite due to the user containing a list of their posts, which will each contain the user, etc. Clearly this cannot be the case, so what *does* the resolver for `Query.users` return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resolver returns only what you make it return. It's not automatically generated based on the types. What it does is: it matched the types of the object according to what you make it resolve.

In this case your resolver would return a list of users, and each user has a name and a list of posts, and each post has a title, body and an author.

And yes, it seems that it can create an infinite data stream, but that's exactly the idea behind [graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory), is that all the data is connected to it's relations and vice-versa.

You can imagine the return data something like this:

```
data: {
        users: [
            {
                name: "user 1",
                posts: [
                    {
                        title: "post 1",
                        body: "post body",
                        author: {
                            name: "user 1",
                            posts: [
                                {
                                    title: "post 1",
                                    body: "post body",
                                    author: {
                                        name: "user 1",
                                        posts: [
                                            {
                                                .....
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                name: "user 2",
                posts: [
                    {
                        title: "post 2",
                        body: "post body",
                        author: {
                            name: "user 2",
                            posts: [
                                {
                                    title: "post 2",
                                    body: "post body",
                                    author: {
                                        name: "user 2",
                                        posts: [
                                            {
                                                .....
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

And again, GraphQL only returns the data you ask it to return. So, if you only want users and posts the query would be something like:

```
query getUsers {
  users {
    name
    posts {
      title
      body
    }
  }
}
```

In this case it would only return the users and their posts, not the authors.

Comment: Thank you. This makes sense now that I look back at the documentation and see that in the examples, one always passes the `info` argument to the ORM.